# I need to redirect the /default page of my application(Sitecore) to another page of my hosted site

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, sitecore

1.I have tried adding the IIS Rewrite Rule which works for local environment but not in the higher environments.
2.Sitecore redirect settings is also not working.
3.Currently (localhost)/default loads the homepage and I need this to get redirected to another page of my site.

Can somebody help me to achieve this without overriding the HttpBeginRequest Processor?

Comment: Does this what you need ?  `public IActionResult Privacy(){return Redirect("https://google.com"); }` I mean when you send a request in an MVC project, it will route to the controller and then in the controller you may redirect the request to another site.

Comment: Yeah that's what I was looking for. Created a route with 'default' and did like you mentioned to get it done. Thanks for your reply! @TinyWang

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`public IActionResult Privacy(){return Redirect("https://google.com"); }`

As you have an MVC project, requests will all route to a controller action, you can set the redirection in the corresponding action.